# Question about notation of expected value, $\mathbb{E}[1_{\{X^2+Y^2\leq{1}\}}]$

Tags: probability, statistics, finance, monte-carlo

I am self-teaching a course in Monte Carlo methods and have a quick question about notation. What is meant by this notation $\mathbb{E}[1_{\{X^2+Y^2\leq{1}\}}]$? I am familiar with expected value but have either forgotten or never encountered the notation $1_{\{X^2+Y^2\leq{1}\}}$. What does this mean? For context, here is the question I am attempting:

Let $X, Y$ be independent and uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Show that:
$$\mathbb{E}[1_{\{X^2+Y^2\leq{1}\}}]=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For any event $A$, $\mathbb{E}(1_A) = \mathbb{P}(A).$

Comment: See it as a function whose value is $1$ in the indicated set, and $0$ everywhere else. In this particular case you will have $1$ in a circular sector with radius $1$ in the first quadrant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any event $E$, the notation $1_E$ typically denotes the *indicator* function of $E$:

$$
1_E = \begin{cases}
1 & E \text{ occurs}\\
0 & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
$$

So,
$$
1_{X^2+Y^2 \leq 1} = \begin{cases}
1 & X^2+Y^2 \leq 1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$